# Issue with code not running after user provides input

Tags: file, input, while-loop

I am in my first year of coding. I am writing a program for school that I currently am having some issues with. The assignment is to create a trivia game using files. My code won't continue after I ask the user for an input to determine how many points the question they are asked will be worth. The section of the code with the problem is posted directly below. My entire program is below that in case that help anyone needs to see the whole thing. Just for the record the entire program is not finished yet.

P.S I am new at this so if I missed something obvious I apologize.

```
while repeat3==True:
    #identifying what point value the player wants        
    print "what point value do you want the question to have?"
    print "your options are:200,400,600,800,1000"
    desiredValue=input()
    print 'testing'
    if desiredValue==200:
        questionValue=random.randint(1,5)
        repeat3=False
    elif desiredValue==400:
        repeat3=False
        questionValue=random.randint(5,9)
    elif desiredValue==600:
        repeat3=False
        questionValue=random.randint(8,13)
    elif desiredValue==800:
        repeat3=False
        questionValue=random.randint(13,17)
    elif desiredValue==1000:
        repeat3=False
        questionValue=random.randint(17,20)
    else:
        print 'please entre one of the good values'
#asking the user the question        
print "Here is the question:"
print temporaryQuestions[currentCategory][questionValue]
```

here is my entire program so far

```
#quiz Master Project
#imports
import random
import time
#variables defined
categorys=["history", "vintage tv", "harry potter", 'mythology']
questionFiles=['history questions.txt','vintage tv show 

questions.txt','HarryPotterQuestions.txt','mythQuestions.txt']
answerFiles=['history answers.txt','vintageTVAnswers.txt','HarryPotterAnswers.txt','mythAnswers.txt']
chosenCategory=0
HistoryQuestionsList=[]
TVQuestionsList=[]
HarryPotterQuestionsList=[]
MythQuestionsList=[]
temporaryQuestions=[HistoryQuestionsList,TVQuestionsList,HarryPotterQuestionsList,MythQuestionsList]


repeat1=True
repeat2=True
repeat3=True
desiredValue=0
name=0
# functions


#_______________________________________________________________________________
#turning the questions into lists
#history questions
a= open ('history questions.txt','r')
reader1=a.readlines()
for line1 in reader1:
    HistoryQuestionsList.append(line1)
#vinatage tv
b= open('vintage tv show questions.txt','r')
reader2=b.readlines()
for line2 in reader2:
    TVQuestionsList.append(line2)
#Harry potter
c=open('HarryPotterQuestions.txt','r')
reader3=c.readlines()
for line3 in reader3:
    HarryPotterQuestionsList.append(line3)
#Mythology
d=open('mythQuestions.txt','r')
reader4=d.readlines()
for line4 in reader4:
    MythQuestionsList.append(line4)

#prompting
print "hello and welcome to (for copyright reasons) japordy!"
print 
print "what is your name?"
name=raw_input()
print 
print "you are going to be able to chose from a few types of questions to answer"
time.sleep(.2)
print
print "you will be asked 10 questions"
time.sleep(.2)
print 
print "first you need to decide what catagory to get a question from then, select a question on the basis of points."
time.sleep(.2)
print 
print "you may chose from a different catagory each time"
time.sleep(.2)
print
print "after you are asked a question that question will be deleted from the questions that you can possibly get"
time.sleep(.2)
print 
print "the point system works like this, if you get a question right you will be given the total number of points that question was worth."
print "But if you get the question wrong you will be fined the number of points that the question was worth."
print "if you take to long to answer you will not get a chance to answer and you will not recieve or be fined points"
time.sleep(3)
print
print "the catagories that you can chose from are: history, vintage tv, harry potter, and mythology"
time.sleep(.2)
print
print "the point values are 200, 400, 600, 800, and 1000"
print
#selecting the questions that will be asked
print "please entre the catagory you want to choose"
chosenCategory=raw_input()
chosenCategory=chosenCategory.lower()#converting all the letters to lowercase
#seeing if the user entered a valid category and if so creating a file that can be used for each round. 
while repeat1==True:
    while repeat2==True:
        for i in range(1,5):
            if chosenCategory==categorys[i-1]:
                currentCategory=i-1
                repeat2=False
        if repeat2!=False:
            #selecting the questions that will be asked
            print "the catagories that you can chose from are: history, vintage tv, harry potter, and mythology"
            print
            print "please entre the catagory you want to choose"
            chosenCategory=raw_input()
            chosenCategory=chosenCategory.lower()#converting all the letters to lowercase
    while repeat3==True:
        #identifying what point value the player wants        
        print "what point value do you want the question to have?"
        print "your options are:200,400,600,800,1000"
        desiredValue=input()
        print 'testing'
        if desiredValue==200:
            questionValue=random.randint(1,5)
            repeat3=False
        elif desiredValue==400:
            repeat3=False
            questionValue=random.randint(5,9)
        elif desiredValue==600:
            repeat3=False
            questionValue=random.randint(8,13)
        elif desiredValue==800:
            repeat3=False
            questionValue=random.randint(13,17)
        elif desiredValue==1000:
            repeat3=False
            questionValue=random.randint(17,20)
        else:
            print 'please entre one of the good values'
    #asking the user the question        
    print "Here is the question:"
    print temporaryQuestions[currentCategory][questionValue]
    UserAnswer=raw_input
```

Comment: what language is this? you should tag this question with that info since experts tend to filter questions.

Answer (score 0):

For Python2, input () may not work. Use raw_input () if this is the case. Secondly, input is a string but you are comparing it with an integer. (1 is 0+1 or 2-1 but "1" is a stick and "2" is load of pixels that look like a swan swimming to the left. You can either compare it to "200" or compare int(desired_value) with 200.
Also, you might want to look at switch(),case,default for this or, since the code is almost identical in each case, an associative array of min/max values:

```
randMinMax = {200: {1,5}, 400: {5,9} ...}
while True:         #infinite loop - see 'break' below
    desired_input = int(raw_input)    #Might want to try/catch in case of bad input
    if desired_input in randMinMax:
        questionValue=random.randint(randMinMax [desired_input][0], randMinMax [desired_input][0])
        break;          # Break out of loop
    else:
        print 'please entre one of the good values'
```

However, there is an even quicker version in this case since there is a fixed relationship between the input value and the random limits so:

```
limit = (desired_input / 200) - 1     # 0 to 4 inclusive
if limit==int(limit) and limit < 5:   # not, for example, 215
    limit = (limit * 4) + 1           # 1, 5, 9, 13, 17
    questionValue=random.randint(limit,math.min (limit+4, 20))   # Because the last limit is 20, not 21 - hence math.min
    break;                            # Got a result, stop looping.
```

A little more than you asked but these principals should help you along as you learn to code. Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: For any future questions, you had better tag "Python" to specify the language.